# Исчез вопрос и все что с ним было связано: ответ, комментарии

Tags: поддержка, удаление-вопросов

Сегодня, часа 3-4 назад, ответил на вопрос (чужой). Под этим ответом была небольшая дисскусия. 
Сейчас заметил, что вся информация пропала. Ни следа. И не понятно почему. Насколько мне известно - удалить вопрос, если под ним уже был ответ - вопрошающий, простой смертный :), не может.
Как узнать причину удаления вопроса?

Comment: Разве не может? Мне кажется автор в любом случае может удалить свой вопрос. Просто ему предупреждение должно было выскочить о том, что не стоит так делать. Но могу ошибаться )

Comment: я пробовал удалить вопрос, под которым был какой-то ответ (не правильный) - мне не позволило. Говорит: что-то типа, люди старались - отвечали, а ты....)

Comment: @Дмытрык, возможно тут дело в том, что не было голосов `за` на ответе. В этом случае вопрос не считается отвеченным и, видимо, автор может его удалять

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Автор может удалить вопрос, если ответов нет, либо если у единственного ответа нет положительного рейтинга. В [твоём случае](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1081300/178988) рейтинг ответа был 0.

Comment: Не "положительного рейтинга", а "голосов за", насколько я помню.

Comment: Классно, я такой сижу, делаю ответ, час прошел, 2 прошло, наконец я нашел все для ответа, подготовил, ответил, прошло время но ЗА и ПРОТИВ нет, ну бывает такое, что никто не хочет давать ЗА или ПРОТИВ тут ТС который вопрос задал, решил удалить и удалил, а я зашел, и нет ничего, вся инфа пропала. Это беда, вообще не серьезно, если бы у меня так случилось я бы вобоще этот ресурс проклинать бы начал. Ибо кучу времени потерял для ответа и тут на тебе.

Comment: @And, можно проголосовать за восстановление ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy, я думаю вам стоит закрепить ссылку тут.