# Удалять вопрос, на который дали правильный ответ – допустимо ли это?

Tags: обсуждение, удаление-вопросов

Был вот такой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1169664/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC-c/1169673) (был удалён), заданный пользователем [@Syponchik](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/403979/syponchik), на который я дал ответ. Ответ был достаточно простой, но автор, по моему мнению, новичок, поэтому не страшно. Но вместо того, чтобы автору дать мне +15/+25 и/или хотя бы (я не говорю, что это правильно) поставить комментарий типа «Спасибо!», он удалил свой вопрос по непонятной мне причине (возможно, посчитал свою проблему "детской").

Со мной такое случалось не раз, но насколько это допустимо?

Comment: Восстановил вопрос, ответ и коммент ТС оставил.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Исчез вопрос и все что с ним было связано: ответ, комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10101/%d0%98%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Comment: Не думаю, что исходники нужны тут в вопросе на Мете.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, не дубликат, потому что там вопрос "куда пропал вопрос и все что с ним связано", а тут "допустимо ли (и что делать в таких случаях)". Там ответа на такую постановку вопроса нет.

Comment: @insolor ну, как минимум, связанные это точно. Отозвал голос.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Бывает, что новички по незнанию удаляют вопрос после того, как получили удовлетворяющий их ответ. Это не правильно: удаляются потенциально полезные для базы знаний вопрос и ответ, ну и естественно удаление демотивирует автора ответа. Нужно принимать меры для восстановления вопроса и разъяснять, почему так делать не нужно.

Я в таких случаях ставлю тревогу с описанием ситуации на вопрос, чтобы модератор восстановил его. После восстановления пишу комментарий автору вопроса, что не нужно удалять вопрос после того как получен ответ, [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1118029#comment1930542_1118029):

> Не нужно удалять вопрос после того как вам дали ответ. Ответы не только для вас, но и для будущих посетителей сайта. Если вы считаете, что ответ вам помог, вы можете отметить его галкой слева от ответа (см. [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))

Comment: Самому тоже можно проголосовать за восстановление.

Comment: @Qwertiy, можно проголосовать самому, если есть 10к репутации. В любом случае для восстановления нужно три голоса от участников с 10к+ репутации, либо один модератор :) Для ускорения процесса можно и проголосвать за восстановление, и поставить тревогу.